# In R data frame for each set of rows and column use value that is not na

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame df of the following structure:

```
observation  x1  x2  x3  x4
"obs1"         NA  NA  NA  51
"obs1"         NA  NA  NA  NA
"obs1"         NA  25  NA  NA
"obs2"         NA  NA  NA  NA        
"obs2"         NA  NA  NA  NA
"obs2"         NA  NA  NA  56
"obs3"         26  NA  NA  NA
"obs3"         NA  82  NA  NA
"obs3"         NA  NA  "x" NA
```

I want a data frame df2 that, for each observation and for each column, takes the one value, that is not NA. The resulting data frame should look like this:

```
observation  x1  x2  x3  x4
"obs1"         NA  25  NA  51
"obs2"         NA  NA  NA  56
"obs3"         26  82  "x" NA
```

I tried to do:

```
only_value = function(x){
   x[which(!is.na(x))]
}
df2 = df %>% lapply(only_value) %>% as.data.frame()
```

However, this only works if there is the same amount of values for each observation. This is not the case in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `only_value` function to return only 1st non-NA value.

```
only_value = function(x){
  x[!is.na(x)][1]
}
```

Now apply this function by group to columns `x1` to `x4` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(observation) %>%
  summarise(across(x1:x4, only_value))

# observation    x1    x2 x3       x4
#* <chr>       <int> <int> <chr> <int>
#1 obs1           NA    25 NA       51
#2 obs2           NA    NA NA       56
#3 obs3           26    82 x        NA
```

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` option using `fcoalesce` may help

```
type.convert(setDT(df)[,data.table(t(fcoalesce(asplit(.SD,1)))),observation],as.is = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
   observation x1 x2   x3 x4
1:        obs1 NA 25 <NA> 51
2:        obs2 NA NA <NA> 56
3:        obs3 26 82    x NA
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(observation = c("obs1", "obs1", "obs1", "obs2",
"obs2", "obs2", "obs3", "obs3", "obs3"), x1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, 26L, NA, NA), x2 = c(NA, NA, 25L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 82L,
NA), x3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "x"), x4 = c(51L,
NA, NA, NA, NA, 56L, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-9L))
```

---

Similarly, you can use `coalesce` with `dplyr`

```
df %>%
  group_by(observation) %>%
  summarise(across(x1:x4,~do.call(coalesce,as.list(.x))))
```

which gives

```
  observation    x1    x2 x3       x4
* <chr>       <int> <int> <chr> <int>
1 obs1           NA    25 <NA>     51
2 obs2           NA    NA <NA>     56
3 obs3           26    82 x        NA
```

Comment: Very interesting to know, thank you! I think the code in the other answer is a bit easier to understand, that's why I will keep the other answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @MaxJ. You are welcome. Your user function is also a good option. I just would like to provide alternatives to show other possibilities :)